# Transferencia de arquivos automatico entre servidores com PHP

Tags: php, linux, sftp

Estou criando uma aplicação que realiza o backup de arquivos em servidores linux. Ele já entra automaticamente no servidor e envia comandos para a realização do backup. O meu problema e que quero mover o arquivo de backup para outro servidor e não estou conseguindo. Para um sistema automático, o uso do scp não esta sendo valido, já que ele requer uma autenticação previa, e pelo PHP não consigo pegar a resposta do servidor dessa autenticação.

Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer esse sistema? E tem como fazer isso por SFTP?

Comment: precisa mesmo passar por toda essa complicação? não poderia resolver com um wget no server que fará o download? (wget é mero exemplo)

Comment: você quer fazer um backup completo do dados e da aplicação ou você quer apenas enviar uma cópia de um arquivo especifico pra outro servidor?

Comment: Quero que do servidor A eu conecte no servidor B e transfira o arquivo do B para o C. Daniel, creio que para a tarefa ser totalmente automatizada o wget nao funcionaria muito bem.

Comment: Vc pode fazer um tarefa no cron, cria um script para criar o backup e outro para dar um wget no backup. Assim vc transfere de um para outro e pode agendar e até mesmo verificar a execução do backup. Estou comentando, mas se acreditar que pode dar certo assim que eu puder escrevo uma resposta detalhada

Comment: Já considerou rsync? O rsync é uma ferramenta poderosa para fazer o que você deseja. Ele sincroniza arquivos entre locais (remotos ou nao) de forma diferencial. Só copia aquilo que mudou. É padrão em qualquer distribuição Linux.

Comment: Um detalhe importante: SCP é um cópia de arquivos segura em cima do protocolo SSH. É possível fazer SSH autenticar sem senha entre dois servidores. É um processo bem simples de fazer, inclusive.